# How to get full width of an element inside an "overflow-x: auto;" area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

I coded this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    alert("Width of #text: " + $("#text").width());
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

#scroll-area {
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

#text {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="scroll-area">
    <div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button>Get width of #text</button>
```

I would like to calculate the width of the `#text` element that is inside the `#container` element. Currently, it shows me `300px` as result. But that is the width of the container, and not of the text element.

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: @nicael It calculates the width of the container, and not of the text element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the overflowed width of an element in a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764658/how-to-get-the-overflowed-width-of-an-element-in-a-webpage)

Comment: It worked, thank you! But this problem → https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71667040/show-and-hide-elements-based-on-scroll-position is still not solved with it. Do you have an idea how to do that? Would be very thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `scrollWidth` feature

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    alert("Width of #text: " + $("#scroll-area")[0].scrollWidth);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

#scroll-area {
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

#text {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="scroll-area">
    <div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button>Get width of #text</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! I actually just asked that because of this quesiton: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71667040/show-and-hide-elements-based-on-scroll-position – unfortunately, using this doesn't help me to solve the problems. Could you please take a look at this?

Comment: I see that you deleted the post but I have resolved the problem. I can share it if you want @Anna_B

Comment: Hey, thank you! I could solve a part of it by my own, and posted a new version of the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71668975/hide-element-if-scrolled-to-maximum-of-container – Can you answer there? Or add a fiddle here?

Comment: I have posted my solution @Anna_B